# Continue prompting till criteria fulfiled

Tags: java, exception

I am practicing exception handling and have more or less grasp the basic concept.

I have been searching up on how to continue execution by prompting user to input the value which fulfills the specific criteria despite catching the exception by using a loop

I have this specific code that request user to enter a value between a range and have an exception handling to catch if a string is being input-ed. However, the program stops executing after it prints out the exception handling.

Any ideas how I can implement a loop or any other method that can continue the program execution after exception handling?

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int num = 0;
try
{
    System.out.print("Please enter a number between 1 to 50 : ");
    num = scanner.nextInt();
} 
catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    System.out.println("Not a number");
    return;
}

while (num > 50 || num < 1) {
    System.out.print("Out of range. Enter a number between 1 to 50 : ");
    num = scanner.nextInt();
}

System.out.println("The number is : " + num);
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using exceptions to handle invalid (i.e. non-int) input: Scanner has the `hasNextInt` method for this specific purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
boolean isInputValid = false; // input flag, valid = true / invalid = false
int num = 0;

while(!isInputValid) {
    try
    {
        System.out.print("Please enter a number between 1 to 50 : ");
        num = scanner.nextInt();

        // Input is a valid integer
        if (!(num > 0 && num < 51)) { // input out of range
            System.out.print("Out of range.");
        }
        else
            isInputValid = true; // input valid, proceed & break loop
    }
    catch (InputMismatchException ex) { // input not an integer
        System.out.println("Not a number");
        scanner.next();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

System.out.println("The number is : " + num);
```

Comment: I'm getting an infinite loop the moment I input a string

Comment: You are expecting an `int` right ? So the loop won't stop unless you get an integer as input

Comment: Yeap only int to be enter however, e.g a string has been entered, it gives an infinite loop immediately.

Comment: Thank you! It worked. As for the other suggestion / help being posted, I'll attempt to try and see how I can use it as I am quite lost without an example of how I can use those specific methods

Answer (score 3):

Exceptions should handle exceptional situations, i.e. situations you couldn't anticipate in advance. Since you can definitely anticipate that the user may enter invalid input, you can handle that invalid input without any exception handling :

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num = 0;
    while (num > 50 || num < 1) {
        System.out.print("\nPlease enter a number between 1 to 50 : ");
        while (!scanner.hasNextInt()) {
            scanner.next(); // discard non-integer inputs
            System.out.print("\nPlease enter a number between 1 to 50 : ");
        } 
        num = scanner.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("You entered " + num);
```

Sample output :

```
Please enter a number between 1 to 50 : -1

Please enter a number between 1 to 50 : 53

Please enter a number between 1 to 50 : ff

Please enter a number between 1 to 50 : rr rr ff

Please enter a number between 1 to 50 : 
Please enter a number between 1 to 50 : 
Please enter a number between 1 to 50 : 13
You entered 13
```

Note that this code is much shorter than the version that uses exception handling.